# Custom response message using MessageContext

Tags: java, rest, jax-ws, httpresponse

I was wondering how I could set a custom response message to my MessageContext? I know how to set the `HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE` like `200`, `404` etc. on server side and how to read them on client side. But how would I set a custom message like "Bad request, key and value can not be empty"? Is there anything which is intended to be used for creating custom response messages?

Server

```
@WebServiceProvider
@ServiceMode(value = Service.Mode.PAYLOAD)
public class MWServiceProvider implements Provider<Source> {

    @javax.annotation.Resource(type=WebServiceContext.class)
    private WebServiceContext wsContext;

    @Override
    public Source invoke(Source source) {
        MessageContext messageContext = wsContext.getMessageContext();
        ...
        // read the source content, which is a key-value-pair for this example
        if (keyValuePair.getKey().isEmpty() || keyValuePair.getValue().isEmpty()) {
            // bad request, key or value can not be empty
            messageContext.put(MessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
            // ??? HOW CAN I SET A CUSTOM MESSAGE LIKE 
            // ??? "Bad request, key and value can not be empty"
            // ??? TO MY MESSAGE RESPONSE CONTEXT?
        } else {
            ...
            messageContext.put(MessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
            ...
        }
        return source;
    }
    ...
}
```

Read status code on client side:

```
Map<String, Object> response = dispatch.getResponseContext();
Integer statusCode = (Integer) response.get(MessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE);
System.out.println("status_code: " + statusCode);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have access to the underlying `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse` via key [MessageContext.SERVLET_RESPONSE](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/MessageContext.html#SERVLET_RESPONSE) in your `MessageContext`.  From there you should be able to set the [error code and message](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError%28int,%20java.lang.String%29).